# Strapi file upload doesn't work in production

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, production, strapi

I have a problem when uploading files in production with strapi. I have deployed strapi on Heroku and I am using the upload-provider-asws-s3 for files upload.
I created a settings.js file in extensions/upload/config with the following code :

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = {
    provider: "aws-s3",
    providerOptions: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      region: "xxxxxxxxx",
      params: {
        Bucket: "xxxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  };
} else {
  module.exports = {}
}
```

but when I connect to the strapi production admin and try to upload files, my s3 bucket won't load the files. I connected the same aws-s3 config to the development mode (just to test) and it worked perfectly. It is like heroku won't connect to aws-s3 but I don't get what I miss in my configuration to be able to upload files in the production mode.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Having same issue! Did you find the solution?

Comment: @KatharinaSchreiber I am sorry but I don't use Strapi any longer. So I am not sure what I did still works today, but I created a plugins.js file : config/env/production/plugins.js with this setup : `module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    upload: {
        provider: "aws-s3",
        providerOptions: {
            accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            region: "eu-west-3",
            params: {
            Bucket: "xxx"
            },
        },
    },
});` I hope it helps !

Comment: @KatharinaSchreiber which one do you use